# The space of measurable functions is Frechet?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, measurable-functions

Take a bounded set $S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ with non-zero measure, and $M_S$ the set of measurable complex functions over $S$.

We know that the convergence in measure is metrizable and complete. Moreover the resulting distance is transational invariant, but it is not induced by a norm, since it doesn't respect the linearity.

As the title said, is this space a Frechet space? Or equivalently, is it locally convex?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#L0,_the_space_of_measurable_functions ... where your space is called $L^0$.  It is an F-space (it is not locally convex, but it is a complete metric TVS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not locally convex.

*Example.*  Let's take $L^0[0,1]$, equivalence classes mod null sets of measurable functions, with base for the neighborhoods of zero given by
$$
V_\varepsilon = \big\{f \in L^0 : \lambda\{\,|f(x)| > \varepsilon\} < \varepsilon\big\}
$$
for $\epsilon > 0$.  I wrote $\lambda$ for Lebesgue measure.  [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#L0,_the_space_of_measurable_functions)

We claim that the constant $1$ belongs to the convex hull of every $V_\epsilon$.  Fix $\varepsilon>0$.  Choose $n \in \mathbb N$ with $\varepsilon > 1/n$.  Then the following functions $f_{n,1},f_{n,2},\dots, f_{n,n}$ belong to $V_\epsilon$.  Function $f_{n,j}$ is $n$ on the interval
$$
\left[\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right]
$$
and $0$ elsewhere.
The convex combination
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n f_{n,j} = 1
$$
is the constant $1$ a.e.

Any convex neighborhood of zero contains one of the sets $V_\varepsilon$, and therefore the constant $1$ belongs to it.  The space is not locally convex.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the proof that $L^p$, $0<p<1$, is not locally convex.